# Matrix product under Loewner ordering

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, order-theory, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let $E$ be a $d \times d$ matrix of full rank. Assume that $E \le A$ in the [Loewner ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order) over positive semidefinite matrices and further assume that $A$ is also full rank. If $P$ is a change of basis matrix, is the following true?

$$P^{-1} E P \le P^{-1} A P$$

If $P$ were orthogonal, I think this is immediate from the conjugation rule (if $X \le Y$ then
$C^T X C \le C^T Y C$ and the converse if $C$ is full rank)on the Loewner ordering as then we have $P^{-1} = P^T$.

This question arose as I have a product $EH$ and know how to control $E$ under the Loewner ordering.  However, I would like to understand its product with $H$ so I applied a change of variables by pre/post multiplying by $H^{1/2},H^{-1/2}$, respectively (assume $H$ is full rank).  The only rule I am aware of is the conjugate rule given above.

Comment: Note that if $A$ is positive semidefinite, then $P^{-1}AP$ is not necessarily positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake -  I actually have positive definite matrices and will update the question accordingly!

Comment: That doesn't really change anything. If $A$ is positive definite, it does not necessarily follow that $P^{-1}AP$ is positive definite (or even positive semidefinite).

Comment: Yes I see the issue.  I think I might be overcomplicating.  Suppose $A = a I_d$ with $a > 0$.  Is it immediate that I have $P^{-1} E P \le a I_d$? My understanding is that this manipulation is not acceptable as only the conjugation rule permits pre-post multiplying.

Comment: No, that doesn't follow. Note that $P^{-1}EP$ might not even be self-adjoint/symmetric

Comment: @BenGrossmann What if $P$ is orthogonal?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Are you asking rhetorically? Either way, yes: if $P$ is orthogonal, then $E \leq A \implies P^{-1}EP \leq P^{-1}AP$.